# vb.net pass data to another class

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, class, soap

I have a class with this function :

```
 Public Function BeginstoreOrders(ByVal printOptions As printOptions, ByVal order() As order, ByVal callback As System.AsyncCallback, ByVal asyncState As Object) As System.IAsyncResult
        Return Me.BeginInvoke("storeOrders", New Object() {printOptions, order}, callback, asyncState)
    End Function

 Partial Public Class order
    
    Private generalShipmentDataField As generalShipmentData
    
    Private parcelsField() As parcels
    
    Private productAndServiceDataField As productAndServiceData
```

No i have to send data to the function

I have try this :

```
 'printoptions
        Dim printoptions As New dpd_label.printOptions
        With printoptions
            .printerLanguage = "PDF"
            .paperFormat = "A6"
        End With

        '-----------------

        'order

        Dim label As dpd_label.order = New dpd_label.order
        label.generalShipmentData.recipient.name1 = "a reciever"
        label.generalShipmentData.recipient.street = "Street blabla"
        label.generalShipmentData.recipient.city = "100"
        'etc ....


        Dim result
        Dim start As New dpd_label.ShipmentServiceSoap33
        result = start.storeOrders(printoptions, label)
```

last line gif a error :
Error   BC30311 Value of type 'order' cannot be converted to 'order()'

The printoptions... i think it will work but how to pass order data ?
I can send the full code .. but its too long to post here. its a soap webservice

Somebody can help ?

Comment: function `storeOrders` expects an array of `order`. Either you change the function signature to expect a single order or you pass an array of orders when calling it

Comment: thanx voor your response ... @ALex B.

 if i do this, : ' 


Dim order(0) As dpd_label.order 
order(0) = New dpd_label.order order(0).generalShipmentData.recipient.name1 = "test name of client" ' 

the old error is gone but it gives a new error if i run the code, on the last line : System.NullReferenceException HResult=0x80004003 Message


 i can not set the value, how i do that ?

Comment: `ByVal order() As order` -- this is bad practice for VB. Change to `ByVal order() As orderArray`

Comment: If you are declaring a variable/parameter that is an array or collection then the name should be plural, to indicate that it can store multiple objects of the type. The parameter should actually be declared `orders As Order()`. Types should always be named starting with an upper-case letter. You can then write sensible code like `For Each order In orders`. Naming conventions are important. You can use whatever you want but don't. Use what pretty much everyone uses because they are tried and tested and consistent with what's already in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I can not change the class (is auto generated by soapui)

i have change my code to :

```
Dim orders(1) As dpd_label.order
        orders(1) = New dpd_label.order()


        With orders(1)
            .generalShipmentData.sendingDepot() = ""  'this line gives a error : System.NullReferenceException: 'De objectverwijzing is niet op een exemplaar van een object ingesteld.'
            'dpd.dpd_label.order.get_generalShipmentData returned Nothing.


        End With

        Dim result
        Dim start As New dpd_label.ShipmentServiceSoap33
        result = start.storeOrders(printoptions, orders)
```

So my question is how to set the variables of te partial class of orders ?